# Fiddler hides sessions - how to show?

Tags: fiddler

I have following setup:

Fiddler on 127.0.0.1:8888,
PHP CURL with HTTP_PROXY env. variable set to 127.0.0.1:8888
Additionally CURL_SETOPT of proxy to the same address.

I had no issues with debug for a long time, while a day ago I did something (or happened something), that caused Fiddler not to show connections initiated from CURL:

they are definitely go through Fiddler, as 
a) without fiddler curl_exec fails and does not return result,
b) in a fiddler window  sessions initiated by CURL definitely count, as I see, for example
no 1 opening of the test page
no 3 opening of the test page

no 2 - had to be CURL post from a test page - but not shown on a session list.

I have an assumption that they are removed by some rule.

What I tried:
  I have
a) studied all Rules menu
b) studied CustomRules.js and Default.ffx for a settings I could miss in the rules menu
c) finally, I have deinstalled & reinstalled back

Unfortunately after reinstall Fiddler still hides CURL connections initiated from test page.

Are there any clues what I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit stupied reason:

in the status bar there is the ticker: "Browser / non Browser"
this option is not duplicated in the menu, thus was not spotted earlier.

Comment: FWIW, in current versions of Fiddler, you can click Help > Troubleshoot Filters to see why requests were being hidden.